# Как в тексте документа упоминать команды

Tags: вёрстка, latex, tex

Необходимо в документе про Latex перечислить команды.
Но при компиляции выходят ошибки.
Пробовала через `\begin{verbatim}\end{verbatim}`. Получается, но при этом в тексте
большие разрывы, как можно по другому это сделать?

Comment: Для текстов можно использовать специальный пакет `listings`. Причем, для больших блоков в отдельном абзаце нужно применять окружение `lstlisting`, а для мелких внутристрочных вставок можно использовать команду `\lstinline`. Последняя является аналогом команды `\verb`, но более гибкая и позволяет раскрашивать синтаксис.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Разобралась.